# Is it possible to know WHY SOQL retrieves EMPTY?

Tags: soql, error, error-messages, debug-logs

I have a SOQL in an APEX Class, and it works okay when I'm logged as a System Administrator User, but it gets empty when I log as a different user. I suppose it could be permissions and field visibility problems... But, I checked out all fields that are in the query, and I see that the second profile has read and edit permissions on all of these fields of the query. Then, I don't see the problem.

So... I would like to know if I can get a message like 'SOQL gets nothing because this...' and the explanation of the problem.

Comment: What about Sharing? Does non-admin user has an access to a record?

Answer (score 4):

If the apex class is running in `with sharing` context then the record level access will kick in the SOQL queries, where it will check if record is shared to the running user or not.

Record Access gets decided by

1. Sharing Setting. (Role based / Hierarchy based, Ownership)
2. OWD (For your object, this might be Private)
3. Apex Sharing
4. Or Manual Sharing (Sharing button)

System admins are having `View All` and `Modify All` permissions which means their profile override sharing rules set in System.

If you want your apex to still return result. just change the class to `without sharing.` and you will get the result.

Comment: That's okay... But I do not need to know what SOQL retrieves (I can see it if I log as SA)... I want to know what is happening in query, because as I said, I checked fields and, apparently, all query fields are read and editable by the other profile.

Comment: Nothing extra is happening , the users does not have record access. What you have checked is object and field level access, which is different than record level access.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using [Restriction Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.restriction_rules.meta/restriction_rules/restriction_rules_about.htm) (new in Winter '22), there's no one single reason why the user can't view the records. It's a combination of the fact that the user does not have View All Data, the Organization-Wide Defaults are set to Private, the user does not own the record, the user is not a manager of the user that owns the record, or hierarchy sharing is disabled, does not own a related parent or child record, has not been shared the record manually, by sharing rule, or territory sharing, etc. In other words, you generally only need *one* reason to have access to a record. If you're not getting a result back, it means that either (a) a Restriction Rule is in place, or (b) all of the other sharing features have not allowed access to this specific record.